# Problem with Nix package manager and GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, devops, nix

I am using the Nix package manager on OSX Mojave.

My colleagues are using earlier versions of OSX.  Not sure if that is the reason they are not encountering this problem.

I can't connect to a specific private gitlab repo that I explicitly have access to.  I can clone it directly, but I can't build it when I am building the project that it is a part of.

This is the relevant excerpt from my default.nix file.  I am told that fetchgitPrivate is deprecated.  I have tried replacing it with fetchGit in this file, but it does not work.

```
      my-private-gitlab-repo = self.callCabal2nix "my-private-gitlab-repo" (pkgs.fetchgitPrivate {
        url = "git@gitlab.com/namehere/my-private-gitlab-repo.git";
        rev = "...";
        sha256 = "...";
      }) {};
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
reallymemorables-MacBook-Pro:localclone reallymemorable$ ./scripts/ghci-backend
building '/nix/store/kljskajsdljkdgfhj-cabal2nix-my-private-gitlab-repo.drv'...
exporting ssh://git@gitlab.com/namehere/my-private-gitlab-repo.git (rev kjsdjfksdjklfsjkldjfksjdfskldf) into /nix/store/kljskajsdljkdgfhj-cabal2nix-my-private-gitlab-repo-asddfs
Initialized empty Git repository in /nix/store/kljskajsdljkdgfhj-cabal2nix-my-private-gitlab-repo-asddfs/.git/
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Unable to checkout khjsdfkhdsjhklsdjhfksdhfjksdh from ssh://git@gitlab.com/namehere/my-private-gitlab-repo.git.
builder for '/nix/store/kljskajsdljkdgfhj-cabal2nix-my-private-gitlab-repo-asdffdsgfd.drv' failed with exit code 1
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/kljskajsdljkdgfhj-cabal2nix-my-private-gitlab-repo.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/kljskajsdljkdgfhj-cabal2nix-my-private-gitlab-repo.drv' failed
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

I'm completely lost on how to proceed.  I have tried putting my ssh keys in Shared and in my normal OSX user.  I have tried a million permissions permutations.

Comment: `fetchgitPrivate` is left over from Nix 1.x; in modern versions, you can just use `builtins.fetchGit`, which does the fetch as your user account, not as the Nix builder. Note the `builtins.` prefix. Re: "tried replacing it with fetchGit in this file, but it does not work" -- let us help you with *that* problem.

Comment: I get this error when I replace with `builtins.fetchGit`: `error: unsupported argument 'sha256' to 'fetchGit', at /Users/reallymemorable/Documents/Git/localclone/default.nix:37:9`

Comment: Yes, `builtins.fetchGit` has different usage; it isn't supposed to take `sha256`, so you can just remove that argument. Search in https://nixos.org/nix/manual/ for the docs -- the accepted arguments are `url`, `name`, `rev` and `ref`.

Comment: (Because `builtins.fetchGit` is building the derivation description, rather than executing it, it can *generate* a fixed-output derivation, thus generating the sha256 of the intended output itself, instead of just needing to *fulfill* one and needing to have a sha256 as input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right thing to use with Nix 2.x is `builtins.fetchGit` -- but it's not a straight-across replacement: You need to remove the `sha256` argument. Because `builtins.fetchGit` runs *under your own user account*, rather than as the Nix builder, it completely moots permissions issues: Anything you can access as yourself (a keyring, a YubiKey or smartcard, or just your `~/.ssh` directory) can be accessed by the copy of `git` invoked by `builtins.fetchGit`.

Thus:

```
my-private-gitlab-repo = self.callCabal2nix "my-private-gitlab-repo" (builtins.fetchGit {
  url = "git@gitlab.com/namehere/my-private-gitlab-repo.git";
  rev = "...";
}) {};
```